# Did Agent Classified and Eva inform the others?

Tags: plot-explanation, penguins-of-madagascar

In the 2014 movie ***Penguins of Madagascar***, when the penguins are in pursuit after busting out of Dave's submarine, it seems to me that ***Agent Classified*** and ***Eva*** came to know about the pursuit by accident, but ***Corporal*** and ***Short Fuse*** are waiting for the octopuses (something like an ambush formation).

***Agent Classified Sighting***:
[image: Agent Classified Sighting]

***Eva Sighting***:
[image: Eva Sighting]

So, Did Classified and/or Eva inform the others about the pursuit and made them to form a rendezvous or did they meet the octopus (and penguins) by accident just like others?